# How to delete object from array using object property - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a todo list that holds a delete button in a grandchild, that when clicked fires an event in the parent - I am wanting this event to delete the array entry corresponding to the grandchild clicked.

**Parent (contains the array and my attempt at the function)**

```
const tasks = [
  { name: 'task1', isComplete: false },
  { name: 'task2', isComplete: true },
  { name: 'task3', isComplete: false },
]

// taskToDelete is the name of the task - doesn't contain an object
deleteTask(taskToDelete) {
    this.state.tasks.remove(task => task.name === taskToDelete);
    this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks });

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'd caution against basing your delete function on name only, unless you're explicitly preventing users from creating multiple tasks with the same name somewhere else in your code (which also may not be ideal, if someone needs to do the same task 3 times, they may want it 3 times). An index/ID based solution would be a safer system to use. `deleteTask` should just accept the index of the task you're attempting to remove.

Comment: @jmcgriz I will be negating duplicate tasks, yes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two issues there:

1. You're seeming to try to direct modify `this.state.tasks`. It's important *not* to do that, never directly modify `this.state` or any object on it. See *"Do Not Modify State Directly"* in [the React documentation for state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).
2. You're passing an object to `setState` that is derived from the current state. It's important never to do that, too. :-) Instead, pass `setState` a function and use the state object it passes you when calling that function. From *"State Updates May Be Asynchronous"* in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly):

   > Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, **you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state**... [Instead]...use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object.

   *(my emphasis)*

I figure your `remove` on an array was intended to be hypothetical, but for the avoidance of doubt, arrays don't have a `remove` method. In this case, the best thing to do, since we need a new array, is to use `filter` to remove all entries that shouldn't still be there.

So:

```
deleteTask(taskToDelete) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const tasks = prevState.tasks.filter(task => task.name !== taskToDelete);
        return { tasks };
    });
}
```

Comment: nice job sir, did great publicity of `prevState` by comments :)

Answer (score 6):

You could simply filter the array :

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    tasks: prevState.tasks.filter(task => task.name !== 'taskToDelete')
}));
```

Also when updating based on `this.state`, its better to use the function form because `setState` is [async](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3).

Answer (score 4):

You can use filter to remove one object from an array following the immutable pattern (filter will create a new array) :

```
deleteTask(taskToDelete) {
    const newTaskArray = this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.name !== taskToDelete);
    this.setState({ tasks: newTaskArray });

}
```

Edit : codepend of the solution : https://codepen.io/Dyo/pen/ZvPoYP

Comment: You've got a typo.

Comment: You **cannot** pass an object to `setState` if it's based on current state. You **must** use the function callback style instead. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: i don't get what you mean, you always need to pass an object to `setState()` method.

Comment: No, you don't. Passing a callback is necessary whenever new state is based on previous state. Again, please see the link in the comment above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why? The event comes from grand child, so what is the problem here? I am not getting your advise for using callback in this case.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: "Why?" is answered **by the link**. (Strongly recommend not having a conversation in two places.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What is asynchronous here? The doc says to use callback approach for Async code.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Did you read the linked section of the documentation?

Comment: I think you're talking about using state and props together like this in the docs : `counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment` so no props here, no need callback.

Comment: @Dyo Yes, his point is correct. But for this usecase of OP what you have fine for me. I am still confused.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This point _React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance..._ ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: If it were fine, would I be spending my time explaining (in my answer, and by linking the documentation) that it isn't fine? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit: The entire "State Updates May Be Asynchronous" section, yes. Primarily: *"Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state."*

Comment: I still disagree with you to take `prevState` as input until I find what is the reason.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: This isn't a matter of opinion. It's not my *opinion* that you cannot base new state on `this.state` and must use the state object passed to the callback instead. It's a statement of fact in the official React documentation.

Comment: @Dyo: No, I'm afraid you're mistaken. Re your edit: Yes, it *seems* to work in simple cases where React doesn't batch updates. It ***fails*** in non-trivial cases where React *does* batch updates. Again: The documentation is quite clear about this. It has nothing to do with props. Quoting (again): *"Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state."* This isn't just me out on my own, this is well-known in the React community.

Comment: To be clear: I'm only pointing this out to try to help you avoid subtle bugs in non-trivial code. Not doing it to be a jerk, genuinely trying to be helpful. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok you got me, you're probably right, i think i never had to use this because the use case was pretty simple, but can be problematic on complex apps. Sorry for being insisting.

Comment: @Dyo: No worries at all, hope it was useful. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement `deleteTask` method as below:

```
deleteTask(taskToDelete) {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    const tasks = [...prevState.tasks];
    const indexOfTaskToDelete = tasks.findIndex(
      task => task.name === taskToDelete
    );
    tasks.splice(indexOfTaskToDelete, 1);
    return { tasks };
  });
}
```

A. Find the index of `taskToDelete`.

B. Then use `splice` method to delete the item from the collection

C. Then call `setState` to update the state with `tasks`.

Comment: I didn't. That is why I wrote `const {tasks} = this.state;` @T.J.Crowder .

Comment: Yes I am trying to understand what are you trying to say here. Not still making any sense. Commented in another thread for the same.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, instead of increasing comment check the link :) and try to understand how setState works, setState is async so you can't trust on this.state inside setState, may be it will update the value with old state value instead of the last updated value.

Comment: updater function will make sure that new state will be updated only with the last updated value :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Ok got it now from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). I need to change my codebase some places now, where I don't see the problem yet, but future can bite me for this. :) Thanks for helping me to fix my knowledge.

Comment: +1, glad it helped you, there is one issue with the updated answer, use this: `const tasks = prevState.tasks.slice(0);` array reference :)

Comment: @MayankShukla: If you could help [Dyo understand this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48385379/157247), you'd be doing them a kindness. I'm afraid I'm not managing it on my own.

Comment: @MayankShukla Fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Great fix Arup!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `higher order` function [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to delete the task.

```
let updatedTasks  =     this.state.tasks.filter(task => task.name !== taskToDelete);

this.setState({ tasks: updatedTasks });
```

Comment: You **cannot** pass an object to `setState` if it's based on current state. You **must** use the function callback style instead. More: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - why? setState takes an object, he is creating a new one, `filter` creates a new array. Sure the callback version is better as you know the state is up to date, but the above is valid (and similar is used in the docs).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not mutating the state directly.

Comment: @dashton: See the link for why. And no, you won't find an example of calling `setState` with an *object* whose data is a modified version of `this.state` in the documentation.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN: I didn't say you were. Read the linked documentation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  `const tasks = prevState.tasks.filter(task => task.name !== taskToDelete);`  this returning modified version of state.  from your comment `And no, you won't find an example of calling setState with an object whose data is a modified version of this.state in the documentation `

Comment: My issue is the use of cannot. You clearly can, but shouldn't if the updates are asynchronous

Comment: @dashton: Cannot if you want your app to work correctly and reliably.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN: Please do read the *"State Updates May Be Asynchronous"* part of the link above. What you're doing above is not the same as that example. The code you've quoted there is fine **because** it uses the callback and the state object given to the callback, not `this.state`. That's the point. You have to use the callback form if you want the state update to work correctly, reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to delete a particular selected Object from the state array:

Here I am using a list of checkBoxes, when I am selecting a checkBox it will add it in the state array and when it gets de-selected then it will get deleted from the array.

```
if (checked) {
            var tempObject = { checkboxValue: data, label: title }
            this.state.checkBoxState.push(resTemp);
        } else {
            var element = data; //data is coming from different method.
            for (let index = 0; index < this.state.checkBoxState.length; index++) {
                if (element === this.state.checkBoxState[index].checkboxValue) {
                    this.state.checkBoxState.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

I got stuck for this question and I am sharing my solution. Hope it will help you.